# Serializing a Django Queryset returns wrong data

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I'm writing a bit of Javascript for my app and I need to get a queryset to my `.js` file by serializing to JSON data first and then returning it to the HTML template. I followed the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/#topics-serialization) and I thought I got it working the first time but I now realized that the data it returns aren't the same with what there is in the database.

Here's my `views.py`:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Poll
template_name = 'voting/detail.html'
context_object_name = 'question'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #note this line below
    context['data'] = serializers.serialize("json", Profile.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user))

    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
    """

    return super(DetailView, self).get_queryset().filter(
        eligiblevoters__user=self.request.user,
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    )

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return super(DetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    except Http404:
        return render(request, 'voting/not_invited_to_poll.html', {})
```

Basically I'm putting into context a JSON serialized Queryset that contains data about the logged in user from the Profile model.

The profile model in `models.py`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    encrypted_private_key = models.BinaryField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    public_key = models.BinaryField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    salt = models.BinaryField(max_length=16, blank=True)
```

The output serialized data that is accessible in my HTML file is [this](https://pastebin.com/zyQsxQQ5)
which looks correct at first but I noticed that even though the user id is correct the fields `encrypted_private_key`, `public_key` and `salt` are nothing like in the database.

The same queryset exported from my database for user id 14 is this:
[image]

I now it looks like a lot of data but just notice that the values for the fields `encrypted_private_key`, `public_key` and `salt` are completely different with what I get in JSON.

For a matter of fact if I remove the filtering of my table in my view like so:

```
 class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'voting/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #I change the line below to return the whole table
        context['data'] = serializers.serialize("json", Profile.objects.all())

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """

        return super(DetailView, self).get_queryset().filter(
            eligiblevoters__user=self.request.user,
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(DetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return render(request, 'voting/not_invited_to_poll.html', {})
```

Now I get the whole table back serialized and what I notice is that those three fields have the same values for all users (in all the rows) even though that's not the case at all.

In the serialized data the `encrypted_private_key`, `public_key` and `salt` has the same value for all users, while in the database each user has a different value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't this simply a consequence of the encoding? JSON and other formats can typically not use all characters in strings, etc. so these are escaped.

Comment: I thought about this too but I can't see anything that matches between what is in my database and what's in my serialized data. Additionally why does the values for these fields are the same regardless the user id? You would assume that even if some characters weren't recognized and were eventually escaped, the values would be still different for each user. Maybe you can't serialize bytes? Those three fields in my model are `BinaryField`s.

Comment: Maybe I need to convert the bytes to a string first but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like Django's JSON serializer encodes `BinaryField` to base64 format by default. That's why the serialized data and the values from my database are completely different. I expected to see the same values but I guess that not the case which makes sense, I just didn't realize it soon enough...